# XmlJavaTypeAdapter throw user defined exception

Tags: jaxb

Is there a way to throw user defined exception in XmlAdapter and catch them when JAXB marshalles/unmarshalls? I mean, I can throw my own exception but JAXB just ignores this exception and throws his own from which I can not get to my exception message or the exception object.

```
try {
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
}
catch (UserDefinedException e) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Sorry for not posting the correct exception that JAXB throwed instead of mine. At this moment, I can not get to the code. Currentlly I am using JAXB-RI, but I used EclipseLink MoXY and encountered this problem.

I will post additional data when I am able to get the hand of the code. But till then, maybe someone knows what am I talking about. Some code example of correct usage of XmlAdapter is also great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation of a [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation is that it throws a `JAXBException`.  This means that any exceptions thrown within something like an `XmlAdapter` is going to end up getting wrapped.  You could potentially use a stateful `XmlAdapter` to handle this use case:

```
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
MyXmlAdpater myXmlAdapter = new MyXmlAdapter();
jaxbUnmarshaller.setAdatper(myXmlAdapter);
jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
if(myXmlAdapter.hasException() {
    // Do something.
}
```

For an Example of using a stateful `XmlAdapter` see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mixing-nesting-and-references-with.html

Comment: Well Blaise, this works like a charm. Thanks. I reverted back to the EclipseLink MOXy. I had problems with my XmlAdapters and JAXB-RI Ant schemagen task, but with MOXy generation of schmea works. To anyone who is reading this comment, I strongly suggest that you use EclipseLink MOXy for your JAXB needs. It will save you a tons of nerves and time.